# Преобразовать текст на php или js

Tags: php, javascript, modx

Есть номер телефона, который висит на сайте. Задается он через панель управления. Как вывести номер телефона с пробелами? 
Например, заменить *+7(999)999-99-99* на *+7 (999) 999-99-99*.
Есть ли решения на js или php?

Comment: в панели управления его задать нельзя с пробелами сразу?

Answer (score 0):

Решение на PHP с помощью [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php):

```
$output=str_replace( array('(',')'), array(' (',') '), $input );
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать функцию форматирования:

```
function format($src, $format = '+d (ddd) ddd-dd-dd') {
    $digits = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $src); // Оставляем только цифры
    $res = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($format); $i++) {
        $letter = $format[$i];
        if (!$digits) { // Не хватило цифр
            $res .= $letter;
            continue;
        }
        switch ($letter) {
            case 'd':  // Цифра
                $res .= $digits[0];
                $digits = substr($digits, 1);
                break;
            default: $res .= $letter;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

$data = [
  '+7(999)999-99-99',
  '79998887766',
  '799988877', // недостаточно цифр для формата
];

foreach ($data as $phoneSrc) {
    echo format($phoneSrc)."\n";
}
echo format('+7 (999) 888-77-66', '+d (ddd) dd-dd-ddd'); // Другой формат
```

Вывод:

```
+7 (999) 999-99-99
+7 (999) 888-77-66
+7 (999) 888-77-dd
+7 (999) 88-87-766
```

[Демо](https://3v4l.org/cXmM9)

Answer (score -1):

**js**

```
'+7(999)999-99-99'.replace(/^([+]\d{1})([(]\d{3}[)])(\d{3})([-]\d{2})([-]\d{2})$/, '$1 $2 $3$4$5')
```

Comment: попробуй писать более развернутые ответы. Добавь описание почему это регулярное выражение решит задачу